# Java Simple Xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, simple-framework

While trying to parse the following XML: -

```
<abc-container container-id="sample-id" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlschema.xsd"/>
  <abc.header>
    <page-count>3</page-count>
  </abc.header>
</abc-container>
```

with the following POJO using lombok: -

```
@Data
@Root(name = "abc-container")
public class ReportDTO {

    @Attribute("container-id")
    private String containerID;

    @Element
    @Path("abc.header/page-count")
    private int pageCount;
}
```

I am getting the following error: -

`Illegal character '.' in element for 'container/.header/page-count' in field 'pageCount' private int com.example.demo.dto.IdcReportDTO.pageCount`

How can I write the @Path value=*'string'* which can correctly parse the element `abc.header`.

Moreover is there an Xpath expression for extracting a number just like there is an XPath expression for the String *(e.g. -> 'container/abstract/**text()**')* type

Comment: Your data binding tool doesn't seem to be able to cope with XML element names that contain a ".". Unless there's some configuration setting to deal with this, you're either going to have to change the XML (e.g to use underscore in place of "."), or find a different tool.

Comment: I am using Simple XML Java lib, so cud u help me how would i configure it for that, moreover is my @Path expression valid ?

Comment: I don't know the specific library so I can't help much. The path expression `container/.header/page-count` is not valid because `.` can appear in the middle of a name but not at the start.

Comment: what about trying to extract an integer, I have seen some XPath expressions like node/sub-node/text() for java String extraction, do I need to do something similar for Java int extraction please?

Comment: I've already told you I don't know this library, and in any case, comments are not for asking supplementary questions.